# How do i use medical codes to determine what disease a person have using jupyter?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'm currently trying to use a number of medical codes to find out if a person has a certain disease and would require help as I tried searching for a couple of days but couldn't find any. Hoping someone can help me with this. Considering I've imported excel file 1 into df1 and excel file 2 into df2, how do I use excel file 2 to identify what disease does the patients in excel file 1 have and indicate them with a header? Below is an example of what the data looks like. I'm currently using pandas Jupyter notebook for this.

Excel file 1:

| Patient | Primary Diagnosis | Secondary Diagnosis | Secondary Diagnosis 2 | Secondary Diagnosis 3 |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Alex | 50322 | 50111 |  |  |  |
| John | 50331 | 60874 | 50226 | 74444 |  |
| Peter | 50226 | 74444 |  |  |  |
| Peter | 50233 | 88888 |  |  |  |

Excel File 2:

| Primary Diagnosis | Medical Code |
| --- | --- |
| Diabetes Type 2 | 50322 |
| Diabetes Type 2 | 50331 |
| Diabetes Type 2 | 50233 |
| Cardiovescular Disease | 50226 |
| Hypertension | 50111 |
| AIDS | 60874 |
| HIV | 74444 |
| HIV | 88888 |

Intended output:

| Patient | Positive for Diabetes Type 2 | Positive for Cardiovascular Disease | Positive for Hypertension | Positive for AIDS | Positive for HIV |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Alex | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| John | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| Peter | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

Comment: Look on here, there are similar questions. Index() and match() could work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `merge` and `pivot_table`

```
out = (
    df1.melt('Patient', var_name='Diagnosis', value_name='Medical Code').dropna()
       .merge(df2, on='Medical Code').assign(dummy=1)
       .pivot_table('dummy', 'Patient', 'Primary Diagnosis', fill_value=0)
       .add_prefix('Positive for ').rename_axis(columns=None).reset_index()
)
```

Output:

| Patient | Positive for AIDS | Positive for Cardiovescular Disease | Positive for Diabetes Type 2 | Positive for HIV | Positive for Hypertension |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Alex | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| John | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| Peter | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |

Comment: Hi can i check if what if for example patient is tagged with an ID for eg. Alex_001. Alex_002, how do i rectify the error of 'Must pass list-like as 'names'.?

Comment: Use something like `df1.assign(Patient=df['Patient'].str.split('_').str[0]).melt(...)...`

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you could melt `df1`, then map the codes from reshaped `df2`, finally `pivot_table` on the output:

```
diseases = df2.set_index('Medical Code')['Primary Diagnosis']

(df1
 .reset_index()
 .melt(id_vars=['index', 'Patient'])
 .assign(disease=lambda d: d['value'].map(diseases),
         value=1,
        )
 .pivot_table(index='Patient', columns='disease', values='value', fill_value=0)
)
```

output:

```
disease  AIDS  Cardiovescular Disease  Diabetes Type 2  HIV  Hypertension
Patient                                                                  
Alex        0                       0                1    0             1
John        1                       1                1    1             0
Peter       0                       1                1    1             0
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could convert your excel file 2 to some form of key value pair and then replace the primary diagnostics column in file 1 with the corresponding disease name, later apply some form of encoding like one-hot or something similar to file 1. Not sure if this approach would definitely help, but just sharing my thoughts.